# ASP.NET Multiple project in same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a situation where I need to have two different project in one solution and map them to different urls, for example `http://*.a.com` maps to project *A* and `http://*.b.com` maps to project *B*.

What's the best way to accomplish this with ASP.NET deployed on an Azure app Service?

Comment: What do you mean "What is the best way?" What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

If you have two projects then its probably better to have two Azure Web apps inside of one App service. It means that apps will be separate but you pay for one App Service.

If you have one project, but as you said you are not, and you want to have different domains with different data, then you should do separation inside of your app.